# The event 'SerialPortUtil.PortListener<DataObject,DataProcessor>.OnNewDataReceived' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= SerialPort C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with the following code

```
public event PortListener<DataObject, DataProcessor>.NewDataHandler OnNewDataReceived
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        add
        {
            this.OnNewDataReceived += (PortListener<DataObject, DataProcessor>.NewDataHandler)Delegate.Combine(OnNewDataReceived, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        remove
        {
            this.OnNewDataReceived -= (PortListener<DataObject, DataProcessor>.NewDataHandler)Delegate.Remove(OnNewDataReceived, value);
        }
    }
```

Event OnNewDataReceived error! How to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage event add/remove yourself, it's up to *you* to store the `delegate`<sup>1</sup>, *separately* from the `event`. Your code inside `add` and `remove` is trying to treat `OnNewDataReceived` as a delegate, which it isn't<sup>2</sup>.

So, add a backing field with the correct delegate type and manipulate *that* inside your `add` and `remove` accessors.

So you'd have something like:

```
private PortListener<DataObject, DataProcessor>.NewDataHandler newDataHandlers;
public event PortListener<DataObject, DataProcessor>.NewDataHandler OnNewDataReceived
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    add
    {
        newDataHandlers += value;
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    remove
    {
        newDataHandlers -= value;
    }
}
```

(Mucking about with `Delegate.Combine` was also pointless since `+=` *does that job*)

---

As it currently stands though, this whole thing looks like wasted effort. I would guess that you're doing this to make adding and removing event handlers "thread safe" by applying the `Synchronized` option. [But](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#field-like-events):

> When compiling a field-like event, the compiler automatically creates storage to hold the delegate, and creates accessors for the event that add or remove event handlers to the delegate field. *The addition and removal operations are thread safe*

(My *emphasis*)

So, really it should just be:

```
public event PortListener<DataObject, DataProcessor>.NewDataHandler OnNewDataReceived;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Or a list of delegates, or some other data structure. After all, that's the reason why you're writing the `add`/`remove` handlers in the first place, isn't it, to manage *how* the event's delegate list is stored?

<sup>2</sup>There is some magic when you use a field-like event which makes the event resemble a delegate under some circumstances. But by providing your own accessors you've opted out of this being a field-like event.

Comment: Hi @damien-the-unbeliever ! Thank you answer. Can you give me an example of how you say it?